# How to increase screen font size in lyx 2.3? (lyx 2.2.3 works)

Tags: fonts, screen, lyx

I want to increase the screen font size in lyx 2.3 because it is extremely small.

However, when I use ctrl+mouse, the font size of some words change, but not the whole document. Please see attached 2.3_before and 2.3_after.[2.3_before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNNn6.png)
 [2.3_after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIy1i.png)

When I turn back to lyx 2.2.3, there is no such problem. Please see attached 2.2.3_before and 2.2.3_after.[2.2.3_before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x326Z.png)
 [2.2.3_after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFDDb.png)

It is super annoying and I don't know how to solve it. I don't want to use lyx but I have to....

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: That looks very annoying indeed. Do you have a High DPI display? What is your operating system? I haven't seen this issue with LyX on Ubuntu. If you do have a High DPI display, I suggest playing with the environment variables discussed here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html (search for e.g. QT_SCALE_FACTOR)

Comment: Thank you. Now I just export the 2.3 file as 2.2.3 and then use the 2.2.3 lyx to finish my work... It is so weird a problem...

Comment: Yeah that is a weird problem. I suggest trying the version 2.3.1, which will be released within a couple of weeks I think and should have some important bug fixes.

Comment: Thank you very much! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem in that after I installed LyX 2.3 it worked fine for a while, but now all LyX files, including the tutorial, display so small as to be unreadable. I haven't been able to discover any way to get them to display at normal size, including uninstalling and re-installing LyX 2.3. I have an HP laptop running Win10. I'll try to go back to an earlier version of LyX.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, if I use the touchpad on my laptop a much smaller screen font size might suddenly appear. The solution is simple use: Ctrl + scroll wheel mouse to increase the screen font again.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the solution in Lyx 2.3.5.2 in kubuntu is, as mentioned above,
Ctrl + scroll wheel mouse to increase the screen font back.

Answer (score 0):

A way to get what you want is Tools -> Preferences -> Screen Fonts and change values to your needs.